# Update YAML file specific components in bulk

Tags: bash, unix, vim, sed, yaml

I want to update my YAML file in bulk for all the second last components in the first level. Something like this:

```
Zero-level:
  First-level-1:
    - Key1: AAA
    - Key2: BBB
  First-level-2: <<< I want to change the name of all second last components
  First-level-3:
```

I used `sed` in the past to bulk update specific keywords in all files within a folder by identifying the keywords, with something like this:

```
sed -i 's/XXX: XXX/XXX: YYY/g' *
```

But for this case, i want to identify every second last item of the first level arrays. The values of which might be different. Also different files might have different numbers of first-level items. File A may be like this:

```
Zero-level:
  First-level-1:
    - Key1: AAA
    - Key2: BBB
  First-level-2: <<< I want to change the name of all second last components
  First-level-3:
```

File B may be like this:

```
Zero-level:
  First-level-1:
    - Key1: AAA
  First-level-2:
    - Key1: BBB
  First-level-4:
  First-level-5:
  First-level-6:
  First-level-7: <<< I want to change the name of all second last components
  First-level-8:
```

Both File A name of `'First-level-2'` and File B's `'First-level-7'` should be changed to the new name I want.

Is there any way I can explore?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `sed` to parse YAML! Can you download an external util like `yq`?

Answer (score 0):

it's risky to process yaml using regex. For example, a value with multiple lines may break the solution.

However, if you are sure all formats of your files follow the format in your question, you can give this a try:

```
tac your.yml| awk '/^  \S/{++c}c==2{$0="  new-name: newvalue"}7' |tac
```

Indentations are important in yaml, so you should put the correct number of spaces there. In the example, I put double spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

replacement=Aloha!

for f in ./*.yml; do
  printf '%s\n' '$-1,s/First.*/'"$replacement/" ,n Q | ed -s "$f"
  echo
done
```

- As what Inian said, use a proper parser for yaml files, this is just the last resort.
- The `,n` is just to show the line number, it will not affect the actual files.
- The leading `./` means the current directory it also a safeguard for files starting with a dash `-`
- The `$-1` is the second to last line, and `$` is the last.
- Change the `Q` to `w` if you think that the output is correct, just make sure you have a backup since the `w` will edit the file in-place.